# Копирование значения свойств объектов с одинаковыми именами но от разных классов

Tags: php

Есть вот такой код:

```
<?php // копирование свойств с одинаковыми именами

    class one {
        public $a;
        public $b;
    }

    class two {
        public $a;
        public $b;
    }

    $o = new one;
    $t = new two;

    $o->a = 1;
    $o->b = 2;

    $t->a = $o->a;  $t->b = $o->b; // нужно заменить на одну операцию

    var_dump($o, $t);

?>
```

[песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a453443157bff95d9f85cce39c6f19752e817aa2)

Как видим в итоге мы имеем **два разных объекта но с одинаковыми именами свойств** и их значениями. Хотелось бы сделать то же самое но без утомительного копирования значений одного свойства в свойство другого объекта при условии, что объекты имеют одни и те же свойства.

Comment: Вами движет академический интерес или вы просто придумали как неправильно решить какую то конкретную задачу?

Comment: @rjhdby мной движет лень ) не хочется пол часа копипастить. там два обсалютно одинаковые класса но просто с очень огромным числом свойств

Comment: Ну ответ то я уже дал, но что-то мне подсказывает, что вы неправильно бутерброд едите.

Comment: @rjhdby все дело в том что если этот бутерброд быстро не съесть то второго уже не получиш ;)

Comment: Второй вариант добавил - он более правильный

Comment: @rjhdby спасибо за хорошую добавочку, будет возможность обязательно поделюсь будербродом

Comment: `не хочется пол часа копипастить. там два обсалютно одинаковые класса но просто с очень огромным числом свойств` - в любой современной IDE (да даже в notepad++) есть поиск/замена по регуляркам с подстановками. Очень спасает когда, например, надо двухстраничный CSV превратить в захардкоженый массив PHP.

Comment: @rjhdby ага. а потом туда пару десятков свойств добавят и\или изменять и ищи по регуляркам ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
$oVars = get_object_vars($o);
$tVars = get_object_vars($t);
foreach($oVars as $var => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($var, $tVars)){
        $t->$var = $value;
    }
}
```

Вариант 2 (более хороший):

[Итераторы объектов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.iterations.php)

[property_exists](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.property-exists.php)

```
foreach($o as $key => $value){
    if(property_exists($t, $key)) {
        $t->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: только в property_exists в первый параметр не объект а класс или имя класса надо передавать

Comment: @perfect `class Имя класса или объект класса для проверки`

Comment: все понял почему у меня с объектом не сработало. родителькие свойства видимо не цепляются.

Comment: Можно конечно пойти совсем адским путем через Reflection. Я бы не взялся, но возможно для вас вариант :)

Comment: знать бы что это )

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php

Comment: мощная вещь но я не настолько отчаянный